# CreateThread parameter failure

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Not sure what is wrong with parameter 3 or the setup?

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from '' to 'unsigned long (__stdcall *)(void *)'
        None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

--

```
void CNumbergeneratorDlg::OnBtn3()
{
    //CreateThread
    hThread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread1, this, 0, NULL);//<--is "this" correct

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread1,INFINITE);
    TerminateThread(hThread1,0);
    CloseHandle(hThread1);
}

DWORD WINAPI CNumbergeneratorDlg::Thread1(LPVOID iValue)
{
    CreateNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

---

??? casting for "this"

```
DWORD WINAPI CNumbergeneratorDlg::Thread1(LPVOID iValue)
{
    (CDialog)iValue->CreateNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

This is what I did with your guys input... thanks

```
    void CNumbergeneratorDlg::OnBtn3()
{
    //CreateThread
    CNumbergeneratorDlg *pp = this;
    hThread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread1, pp, 0, NULL);

//  WaitForSingleObject(hThread1,INFINITE);
//  TerminateThread(hThread1,0);
//  CloseHandle(hThread1);
}

DWORD WINAPI CNumbergeneratorDlg::Thread1(LPVOID iValue)
{
    CNumbergeneratorDlg *pp = (CNumbergeneratorDlg*)iValue;

    pp->CreateNumber();
    return 0;
}

void CNumbergeneratorDlg::CreateNumber()
{
    long m;
    j = 0;
    for(long i = 0; i < 1000;i++){
        m = 0;
        for(long k = 0; k < 1000000;k++){
            m ++;
        }

        j++;
    }

    AfxMessageBox("Done count");
    TerminateThread(hThread1,0);
    CloseHandle(hThread1);
}

void CNumbergeneratorDlg::OnBtn4()
{

    TerminateThread(hThread1,0);
    CloseHandle(hThread1);

    CString c;
    c.Format("%d", j);
    MessageBox(c);
}
```

Comment: For CreateThread you need a static threadproc function. Cannot call it with a member of an instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare the function `Thread1` as a `static` member function in `CNumbergeneratorDlg`? If not, please do so.

Non-static class functions have an implicit additional parameter for `this`. So, type casting will not work. On the other hand, static methods do not carry `this` parameter.

Then, you might wonder how you can access class members inside `Thread1`. A typical technique is passing `this` via `iValue`.

Comment: Based on the declaration in the error message, CreateThread() expects a function taking one member of type void* as parameter. Non-static member functions don't qualify as such because they take an implicit pointer to the object ("this") as parameter. The only possible member function this function can take is a static one. Even this might not work because the function seems to also require to use C calling conventions.

Comment: In CNumbergeneratorDlg's header put "static DWORD WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID iValue)". In CreateThread use "CNumbergeneratorDlg::Thread1" instead of just "Thread1"

Comment: I know the static... I mean passing "this"  I have problems recasting it

Comment: (CNumbergeneratorDlg *)iValue should work. But you should fix the Thread1 method first and make it static and use the proper signature to call it first

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to pass CreateThread a class method which doesn't have the signature it expects. The first argument of all methods is the same type of the this pointer, in the case of Thread1, an CNumbergeneratorDlg*.

You should:

- Make the method Thread1 static, or
- Move it outside the class.

Here is an article on static methods which shows how you should use static in this situation:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr039.htm

Here is an article that may be of use when using CreateThread:

http://adilevin.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/createthread-an-example/

I also suggest you read the following, to understand calling conventions (the '__stdcall' bit):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`Thread1` is a non-static member function. Calling it requires an instance of your class (`CNumbergeneratorDlg`). That's why you get that error.

You could make `Thread1` static, and pass `this` by parameter when creating the thread:

```
class CNumbergeneratorDlg {
    void OnBtn3() {
        hThread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread1, this, 0, NULL);
        // ...
    }
public:
    static DWORD Thread1(LPVOID lpdwThreadParam) {
        CNumbergeneratorDlg *instance =
            static_cast<CNumbergeneratorDlg *>(lpdwThreadParam);
        // do something with instance.
    }
};
```